# Can we assign more than one role to EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I see that there is only one role that can be assigned through aws console.

A role can have multiple policies.

Is there a possibility/necessity to assign more than one role to EC2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible nor there is a necessity.

If your IAM Role needs to access multiple resources, you can do so by attaching multiples policies to a single IAM Role.

For more information, check [Policies and Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html)

Comment: But EC2 can have instance profile that can hold more than one role? I have been told to add one more role in existing instance profile of EC2. CloudFormation template does not support EC2 reference to roles, it supports EC2 reference to instance profile

Comment: No, that’s not possible. Please check @BestPractices’s answer because he mentions the instance profiles. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `"Roles" : [ String, ... ]` is the syntax

Comment: Yep, that parameter is a weird one. They must have changed their mind at some stage.

Comment: Weird one? Do you think CloudFormation template allows to add more than one role in instance profile? am not sure...

Answer (score 3):

AWS does not support the ability to assign more than one instance role to an instance.

From the AWS user guide:

```
An instance profile can contain only one IAM role. This limit cannot be increased.
```

The instance can be assigned a role and that role can be assigned multiple policies. Or you can create a single policy that contains all permissions necessary for that instance.

See: [Instance Roles for EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)